# Efficient way to delete large number of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Consider this query

```
Delete from T1 where T1.ID in  (select ID from T2)
```

Both T1 and T2 are massive tables in the order of millions of records.

T1 is a "live" table and T2 is an "archive" table. After we copy records from T1 to T2, we want to clear it out from T1. T1 is read optimized with many indexes.

What is the efficient way to perform this operation ?

I'm in .net environment, so code based solution will also work.

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete the data in batches to avoid locking, growing transactional log and reclaim the space in transaction log
2. There are no universal method to delete the data effectively. You have to try to use all THREE methods for your table DB design:

   - IN (SELECT ...)
   - EXISTS ()
   - INNER JOIN

In most cases, for large number of rows, EXISTS and INNER JOIN outperforms IN (SELECT..), and often EXISTS outperforms INNER JOIN

Comment: I checked the query plan for IN (SELECT) and EXISTS - they are exactly the same. Does it make a difference in run time ?

Comment: You may have same run time, but the execution plan can be changed in the future if you add more data, so the difference may be significant. From my experience (and from what I read online), the order of choice is EXISTS, then INNER JOIN, then IN. If you do you update in batches, it does not really matter which method to use.

Answer (score 1):

For performance of the database it is best to delete batches of records so that locking is minimised.

```
DELETE TOP (1000)
FROM T1
WHERE T1.ID IN (SELECT ID    
FROM T2)
```

You can optimise the number of records that are deleted.

Re-run the script until no records are deleted